# C/C++ Pointer in struct

Tags: c++, c

```
    typedef struct list {
        int value;
        list *next;
    }list_t;

    void init(list_t *head) {
        head->next = NULL;
    }
```

Can you explain me that what difference  between `list` and `list_t`?
I know declaration struct list list_t, but if I will declarate parametr `list_t parametr, patametr.[...]` I think this is the same effect as `list parametr, parametr.[....]`
I don't understand what mean `list *next` it's the same like `list_t *next` ?

Comment: In C++, there is no need to `typedef` a struct. C != C++, so in general you should not cross tag.

Comment: The linked answer is about C. In C++ there is no difference, so using a `typedef` makes no sense (`struct list {...};` is enough).

Comment: therefore what mean ```list *next```? its the same what ```struct list *next``` or ```struct list_t *next```?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat There is technically a difference, but it is too subtle to care about.

Comment: @eerorika • the subtle difference in C++ being that `struct` "namespace" is a fallback after the regular namespace search comes up empty...?

Answer (score 0):

In c, structs has their  own namespace. list_t is an alias for the struct.